# Why does this return False

Tags: python, python-2.7

I can't understand why this code returns False:

```
list_of_disks = [[170, 158, 470, 0.1], [135, 176, 410, 0.2], [100, 193, 350, 0.3], [170, 458, 470,       1.1]]
def f1(pos):
    for x in range(0, len(list_of_disks)):
        if list_of_disks[x][3] == pos:
            print list_of_disks[x+1][3] - 0.1, list_of_disks[x][3]
            print list_of_disks[x+1][3] - 0.1 == list_of_disks[x][3] # Why is this False..?
            break

f1(0.2)
```

When I print out the 2 values, they seem to be the same..?
Hope someone can help me out here, thanks!

Comment: Floating point cannot be relied upon to be that accurate.

Comment: See the Python Tutorial's ["Floating Point: Issues and Limitations"](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).  See also ["What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: i think precision is the matter here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because 0.1 cannot be stored by computers (there is no exact binary representation of it), so 0.3-0.1 is not the same as 0.2 to python:

```
>>> 0.3-0.1==0.2
False
```

See http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/ for mor details on floating point precision.

You can avoid those pitfalls by using the `Decimal` module, an implementation of exact decimal floating point arithmetic.

> ```
> The purpose of this module is to support arithmetic using familiar
> "schoolhouse" rules and to avoid some of the tricky representation
> issues associated with binary floating point.  The package is especially
> useful for financial applications or for contexts where users have
> expectations that are at odds with binary floating point (for instance,
> in binary floating point, 1.00 % 0.1 gives 0.09999999999999995 instead
> of 0.0; Decimal('1.00') % Decimal('0.1') returns the expected
> Decimal('0.00')).
> ```